# MP test for different distributions

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

I've solved problems of doing mp test for different theta value in one distribution before.
However, I have no idea for doing an MP test when

```
H0: X follows Uniform(0,1) vs H1: X follows exp(1)
```

How to achieve this?